# How do I write an app which takes advantage of a rooted phone?

Tags: android, android-manifest, root

I know I can use "su" to execute commands as root.  Android pops up a user-dialogue to ask whether the app should be allowed to use su, and whether is should remember the user's decision for next time.

Are there things an app can do on a rooted phone, that they can't on an unrooted phone.

If so, what are they, and how are they enabled in the manifest?

---

I want to make the context plain.

I have a supposedly rooted Android device with no access to the Android marketplace.

I have not yet found a way of downloading apks from the play store without putting information about my phone into Chrome extensions which I do not trust.

I need to write a small app to find out if the device is rooted.

Many apps require rooted devices, so if I can write an app that does the same as them, I will know if the device is rooted.

One of the things I would like to do on this rooted device is to shut it down without user interaction.

Comment: Why the two down votes?

Comment: Another down vote - please tell me why.  I'm not trying to hack devices, I just want to understand rooting.

Comment: I can't speak for all downvoters, but the biggest issue with your question is that it is incredibly broad- there is no short and defined list of actions you can do with root. It's a little like asking what app you can write with the Android SDK- the sky is the limit.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there things an app can do on a rooted phone, that they can't on an unrooted phone.

Yes, in the same way that there are things that a super user can do on a Linux computer that a normal user cannot.

> If so, what are they, and how are they enabled in the manifest?

There isn't really a list of things only available to rooted users. The number of things is long, depends on the device, and likely wouldn't really address your real question anyway.

In short, the answer is that you can perform privileged actions that are typically not available to applications or users using the command line.

In practice, this means you can access restricted parts of the filesystem (such as the Android system directory), including data from other applications (such as the normally protected `SharedPreferences`). This also means that you can access restricted commands/applications, such as `sqlite3` (if installed).

If you are looking for a reason to write an application that leverages root access, you are likely going about this the wrong way. Instead, think of what functionality you want and determine if you need root access after that.

Comment: Do all apps on a rooted phone have these abilities?

Comment: In the context of security, I would assume that any app you install on a rooted device could potentially leverage these items. Most apps wont do any of these things because most devices aren't rooted, but once you are rooted you open up the possibility.

Comment: Sorry, I could not interpret your last comment as an answer to my question/comment.  If I have a rooted device, could any app I install do things which require root permission?  Or are root-permissions on a rooted phone controlled in some way?

Comment: From an operating system standpoint, any app could do whatever it wants if  the `su` binary is available. In practice, most rooting methods offer some form of protection in the form of an app (e.g. SuperSU) that manages access to `su` so the user has some control over what apps get root access. [This is a good overview](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/96737/16130).